# If in a $\triangle ABC,b=3$ cm,$c=4$ cm and the length of the perpendicular from $A$ to the side $BC$ is $2$ cm.How many such triangles are possible?

Tags: trigonometry

If in a $\triangle ABC,b=3$ cm,$c=4$ cm and the length of the perpendicular from $A$ to the side $BC$ is $2$ cm.How many such triangles are possible?

---

I found $CD=\sqrt{AC^2-AD^2}=\sqrt5$
I found $BD=\sqrt{AB^2-AD^2}=2\sqrt3$
Area of triangle $ABC=\frac{1}{2}\times 2\times(\sqrt5+2\sqrt3)=\frac{1}{2}\times 4\times 3\times\sin A$
$\sin A=\frac{\sqrt5+2\sqrt3}{6}$
I am stuck here.

Comment: It $b$ the name of the side opposite of the angle $B$, and so on?

Comment: Yes $b$ is the side opposite to angle $B$

Comment: $6$ triangles are possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Hint: In the above picture, circle $c$ has radius $3$ and circle $d$ has radius $4$ while $B$ and $C$ lie on the $x$-axis. Can you continue?

Comment: Can you make the circles again as they are confusing.